# Send message server socket in Meteor to client in Java

Tags: java, sockets, meteor

I want to send message from Meteor application to a Java app, Meteor app is the server socket and Java the client;

My goal is to write a message in a textbox in Meteor app and send to Java using sockets.

Can someone point me out whats the mistake in my code?

My code: 
Meteor

> my.html

```
Template.hello.events({
 'click #hola'(event, instance) {
   Meteor.call("method_socket", "say_hello"); // for each click I want to send a message to java
 }
});
```

> myServer.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
var net = require('net');

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // Here is necessary start the server socket
  var net = require('net');
  var server = net.createServer(
    function (connection) {
      console.log('client connect');
      connection.on('end', function () {
        console.log('client end');
      });
      connection.on('error', function () {
        console.log('client error');
      });
      connection.on('close', function () {
        console.log('client close');
      });
      connection.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("received :", data.toString());
      });
      connection.write('Hello World!\r\n');
      connection.pipe(connection);
    }   
  );

  server.listen(666, function () {
    console.log('server is listening');
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    method_socket: function (message) {
         // I can´t send this message to Java app I had tried:
         server.connection.write(message+'\r\n'); 
          //connection.write(message+'\r\n');
    }
  });

});
```

My Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket smtpSocket = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;
    PrintStream output;
    try {
        smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 666);
        os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
        output.print("Rastalovely");  //  Send to Meteor this message
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
    }
    if (smtpSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
        try {
            String responseLine;
            while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                //    wait the response from Meteor
                System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
                if (responseLine.indexOf("Ok") != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();
            smtpSocket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any console output / error?

Comment: just  "cannot read property write of undefined ", when use  : server.connection.write(message+'\r\n');

Comment: I see, because connection is not in shared context, your method does not know connection because server is a variable created on startup. Make it a variable outside Meteor.startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the connection in the method, you need to make it available, i.e. by declaring it outside `Meteor.startup` I also favour to declare Meteor methods on top level code in order to init them before startup is called:

```
var net = require('net');
var server;

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // Here is necessary start the server socket

  server = net.createServer(
    function (connection) {
      //...
    }   
  );

  server.listen(666, function () {
    console.log('server is listening');
  });

});

Meteor.methods({
    method_socket: function (message) {
        // I can´t send this message to Java app I had tried:
        server.connection.write(message+'\r\n'); 
        //connection.write(message+'\r\n');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your idea is write this : server = net.createServer(
    function (connection) {...}
  ); into method_socket ?

Comment: You could also call net.createServer in the method, but that would create the server and connection each time the method is called, which is why you make server as variable available to the method b ut initialize it on startup.